# linq lamba how can i query a list of child properties and return the parent

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, collections

Consider the following query:

I have the follow structure:

```
Member
{
  public Guid ID
  public string Name
  public virtual ICollection<MemberCategory> MemberCategories { get; set; }

}

MemberCategory
{
  public Guid TribunalMemberID
  public DateTime? AppointedFrom { get; set; }
  public DateTime? ExpiresOn { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to list all the names of all the members who match this query, and I think I need to use `SelectMany` but I can work out the code.

I have tried variations of this:

(`Members` is a collection of `Member`)

```
public IDictionary<Guid, string> Options => Members.
            .SelectMany(tm => tm.MemberCategories)
            .Where(tmc => tmc.AppointedFrom <= DateTime.Today && tmc.ExpiresOn > DateTime.Today)
            .ToDictionary(tm => tm.ID, t => $"{tm.Name}");
```

but I can't understand how to query the collection on the list of members to get back to the list of members to see what matched.

Ideally I want to return the Member ID and the Name

I hope that makes sense.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the `.Any()` method

```
var collection = members.Where(x => 
    x.MemberCategories.Any(tmc => tmc.AppointedFrom <= DateTime.Today && tmc.ExpiresOn > DateTime.Today))
        ToList();
```

Comment: Thankyou. Totally over thinking that one. Simple and clear explanation.